# WSO2 APIM 4.1.0 Admin Portal getting 403 error on login

Tags: java, authentication, tomcat, wso2, wso2-api-manager

When I try to login to the admin portal, I get a 403 error [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LO5KX.png)

But simultaneously, I can enter the dev portal and publisher with the same credentials. The logs show nothing, I tried to turn on the debug, but there is little information there. Basically, this is how the connection happened and nothing more. I also added to the user the roles needed for the admin portal via UI wso2 carbon.

I tried to restart the API manager and configured the user through ui wso2 carbon. I've tried logging in incognito but to no avail.

I don’t know yet in which direction to dig further, so I will be grateful for any answer.

Comment: Are you using WSO2 IS also or is it only APIM? Can you log in to admin portal with the default admin user?

Comment: For authorization, I use only APIM, the default admin user cannot log in either, although the rights should be enough. There's something different here

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the user doesn't have the required permission to log in to the portal. First try opening the Network tab in the browser console and check the response related to  https://localhost:9443/admin/services/auth/introspect call. It should have following scopes. If it is not there, that means user does not have the correct permission to log in. Please check https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/administer/managing-users-and-roles/managing-users-for-admin-portal/ to see whether you have set it correctly.

[image]

Comment: True, some fields are missing, which is strange, because in ui wso2 carbon I added everything that is possible, where else can you manage the permissions?
Here is the scope I have: scope: "apim:api_import_export apim:api_product_import_export apim:app_import_export apim:mediation_policy_create apim:mediation_policy_view apim:monetization_usage_publish apim:tier_view openid"